# Impedance Calculations for Parasitic Resistance, Capacitance, and Inductance

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance

I have recently taken a look at basic electrical engineering topics, and I am having difficulty calculating impedance for parasitic elements. I am trying to find the impedance formulations for real-world resistors and capacitors using their first-order circuit models. Below are the diagrams I used from the textbook.

Resistor Model:

[image: First-Order Circuit Model for a Resistor]

Capacitor Model:

[image: First-Order Circuit Model for a Capacitor]

Please help me with the derivation for their impedance formulation and the corresponding magnitudes and phase angles. Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:

The problem I am having is getting to the textbook formulations from the above diagram.

Formulas from the textbook:

$$|Z(\omega)|=\sqrt{\frac{R^2(1 - LC\omega^2)^2 + (L\omega)^2}{1 + (RC\omega)^2}}$$
$$\phi = \phi_1 - \phi_2$$
$$\phi_1=arctan\left(\frac{L}{R}\left(\frac{\omega}{1-LC\omega^2}\right)\right)$$
$$\phi_2=arctan(RC\omega)$$
(Resistor)

$$|Z(\omega)|=\sqrt{\frac{(1-LC\omega^2)^2+(RC\omega)^2}{(C\omega)^2}}$$
$$\phi = \phi_1 - \phi_2$$
$$\phi_1=arctan\left(\frac{RC}{1-LC\omega^2}\right)$$
$$\phi_2=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
(Capacitor)

So far, I've got:

$$Z(\omega)=\frac{R}{1+(RC\omega)^2}+j\left\{\omega L-\frac{R^2C\omega}{1+(RC\omega)^2}\right\}$$ (Resistor)

$$Z(\omega)=R+j\left(\omega L-\frac{1}{C\omega}\right)$$ (Capacitor)

At this time, I have little idea as to how to proceed and derive the textbook formulas.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to SE. "Do my work for me" questions aren't allowed here. Show what you tried, and people will help you get it right. Thank you.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: The answer really depends on your knowledge. Do you know how to compute modulus and argument for a complex number? If yes, there's no subtlety, it's a straightforward computation.

Comment: I do know how to compute the modulus. It is just that it is my first time working with impedance for three components. I don't know how to derive the phase angles (for both) and the magnitude (for resistor). Actually, I am not particularly sure if I got my math at the end correct.

Comment: The phase is just the argument of the complex impedance. I'll write an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule, it's rarely a good idea to make the denominator real, it tends to make computation cumbersome.

For the resistor case, let's start with:

$$Z=jL\omega+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R}+jC\omega}
=\frac{R(1-LC\omega^2)+jL\omega}{1+jRC\omega}$$

The modulus of a fraction is the fraction of the moduluses:

$$\lvert Z\rvert=\sqrt{\frac{R^2(1-LC\omega^2)^2+(L\omega)^2}{1+(RC\omega)^2}}$$

The argument of a fraction is the difference of the numerator's argument and the denominator's argument.

$$\arg(Z)=\arg(R(1-LC\omega^2)+jL\omega)-\arg(1+jRC\omega)=\varphi_1-\varphi_2$$

$\varphi_2$ is immediate, since $1+jRC\omega$ has a positive real part, so its argument is in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$:

$$\tan(\varphi_2)
=\frac{\text{Im}(1+jRC\omega)}{\text{Re}(1+jRC\omega)}
=RC\omega
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
\varphi_2=\arctan(RC\omega)
$$

$\varphi_1$ has a little trick, since $R(1-LC\omega^2)+jL\omega$ doesn't have an always-positive real part:

$$\tan(\varphi_1)=\frac{L\omega}{R(1-LC\omega^2)}$$

So there are two cases, and your book forgot one (unless there's an additional assumption somewhere you didn't mention):

- If $1>LC\omega^2$, inverting $\tan$ is immediate:
  $$\varphi_1=\arctan\left(\frac{L\omega}{R(1-LC\omega^2)}\right)$$
  which yields the result you gave.
- If $1<LC\omega^2$, then:
  $$\varphi_1=\pi+\arctan\left(\frac{L\omega}{R(1-LC\omega^2)}\right)$$

The capacitor case is much simpler, since you have a single complex number with a positive real part.

As you can see, there's no physics in there, it's pure complex number manipulations.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Complex exponents didn't even come to my mind since my area of study tends to stay far away from even slightly abstract concepts :p Guess I didn't know much about calculating the modulus of complex numbers. Thanks for the help!